# How to find ranges for the 'rate' property of NSSpeechSynthesizer?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, speech-synthesis

I have an OS X app which uses the `NSSpeechSynthesizer` class to read some text. I need to be able to set the speed of the reading, which is done using the `rate` property of `NSSpeechSynthesizer`. However, different voices have different baseline reading rates and different ranges as well. The problem is that I cannot find a way to get this range from the voice so that I know what values are acceptable for the voice. This is important since I want to be able to abstract from the difference in ranges and just let the user choose something like slow/normal/fast. But for a voice with a baseline of 180 words for a minute a value of 100 would be considered slow, which clearly is not the case for a voice with a baseline of 100 words per minute.

Is there a way of getting those ranges? I didn't find anything useful in the class reference for `NSSpeechSynthesizer`.

Comment: Did you say that your issue is that you can't get the voices to be at constant rates because of the different voices? So I suppose it's imperative that you have different voices? You could always use your own custom NSVoice object and give it the same attributes as the others, only make the rate a constant. Use these attributes in your objects and the code should work out fine. Although you are correct, there should be a way to set the baseline text reading speed :(

Comment: Well, I can set the same rate for all the voices (in words per minute), but that wouldn't be right. The thing is, people talk with different speeds so there is a difference in what rate is natural for a person (and thus also for a synthetic voice). So my slow/normal/fast values need to be relative to the baseline. I will probably set slow to be half the normal speed and fast to be double and see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the rate of a voice before you change it, and you could estimate that the acceptable range is the default rate ± 50 WPM or something.

That said, if you're using this to set up a slider, I'd caution you against limiting the user to only “natural”-sounding ranges. Some people, including many blind people, deliberately crank it up as fast as they can stand in order to save listening time.

Comment: just note that if the rate is fast, say 220, and you take it below range, say 50, it will keep speaking at the fast rate, rather than going to the lowest available rate

Comment: likewise the other direction. I found in experiments that the base rate is 180 wpm, the lowest is 90 wpm and the highest is something like 700 or so. Probably 0.5x to 4x is the safe range.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know this isn't the answer you may have been looking for, but as far as I can tell, Apple hasn't made available to the public a way to change the baseline speed of an instance of NSSpeechSynthesizer object (which, as you said, has a 'rate' instance, but it cannot make constant rates for *each distinct voice*). For this, and I know you won't like it, you'll have to make the slower ones faster and the faster ones slower until they about match up. Sorry again, but as far as I know, Apple doesn't offer a way to change the baseline rate. Happy coding!

~Monkeyanator